# fgets meets with segmentation fault under gdb but not when running normally

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

The following program (which does nothing) runs fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *current_string = NULL;
  fgets(current_string, 16, stdin);

  return(0);
}
```

When I run it under GDB, however, the `fgets` call triggers a segmentation fault.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000332ec67ee0 in _IO_getline_info_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.9.x86_64
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x000000332ec67ee0 in _IO_getline_info_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000332ec66d29 in fgets () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000400536 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd4e8) at test.c:7
```

As far as I'm aware, I've been following the proper usage of the `fgets` function, and I don't understand what's happening.  What have I done wrong?

I'm compiling with gcc with the `-g` option (for debugging information) on RHEL.

Comment: what are `current_string`, `in_stream`? Most likely you're triggering  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). somewhere. Show the related code.

Comment: Sorry; fixed now.  I miscopied in my SSCE, but it should be reproducible now.

Comment: _As far as I'm aware, I've been following the proper usage of the fgets function_ - why do you think this is proper?

Comment: OK, yes I see now.  I never allocated memory for the string anywhere.  what a silly mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code,

```
  fgets(current_string, 16, stdin);
```

`current_string` is initialised to `NULL`, so essentially you're trying to write into an invalid pointer.  It invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory to `current_string` before you can actually *write* something into it ( into the *memory location* pointed by it, to be exact) .

Rather, as per *this* snippet, I don't see a reason to use `current_string` as a *pointer*. You can easily write something like

```
 #define MAX 16

char current_string[MAX] = {0};
fgets(current_string, MAX, stdin);
```

and make it work.

Comment: well, current_string is very much initialized, it just points to memory that he shouldn't be writing to.

Comment: Initialising it with `NULL` was not around in the question's 1st version. @MK.

Comment: @MK. Thanks, for pointing that out, misread the code. :-) Updated now.

Comment: whoa, right, so technically I can't be _blamed_. Thankt to you too @alk sir. :-)

Comment: @mch True indeed. should be a `0`, as I've already corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling fgets() to write to memory at address 0 which is not allocated to you.  This is undefined behavior which in most circumstances will lead to a segfault.  I'm a little surprised it doesn't always, but I don't care, that's what undefined behavior does.
You need to allocate the buffer for fgets using malloc() call.